# Import Text Wizard - Error in loading DLL

Tags: microsoft-office, 64-bit, office365, microsoft-access, debug

Clicking the Finish button on Access' Import Text Wizard generates "Error in loading DLL".

Current suite: MS Office 365 ProPlus a/k/a E3, 64bit, Version 1902 (Build 11328.20392 Click-to-Run).

Previous suite: MS Office Business Premium; did not generate this error.

Current OS: Windows 10 1803

I uninstalled (via Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant for Office 365), re-installed, and repaired MS Office 365 ProPlus 32 and 64 bit editions.

I ran sfc /scannow and dism.exe /online /Cleanup-image /ScanHealth; which reported no issues.

I repaired all Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable packages.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\ACCWIZ\ is a Trusted Location in Access.

The WinDbg Preview debugger returns the following at the error:

mincore\com\oleaut32\typelib\tlibapi.cpp(2284)\OLEAUT32.dll!00007FFE6465601D: (caller: 00007FFE64645274) ReturnHr(2) tid(290c) 8002801D Library not registered.

I have re-registered OLEAUT32.dll, dao360.dll, and all other .dlls under c:\WINDOWS\system32\ and c:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\, to no avail.

On another like PC the dll, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\MSOSTYLE.DLL, is the last module loaded prior to clicking the Finish button on Import Text Wizard.  However I don't see this module load via the debugger on the subject PC; but the module is listed using lm:

00007ffe`5a420000 00007ffe`5a431000   MSOSTYLE   (deferred)

I am seeking additional debugging tips or other possible solutions.

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/833220/error-in-loading-dll-error-message-when-you-run-a-microsoft-access-wiz) to see if it helps.

Comment: @Bella - Thank you for the link. I tried registering those specific DLLs earlier; however, that did not resolve the issue.